# Shorter menu titles in grub2

Tags: linux, fedora, grub2, boot-loader, boot-menu

I would like to make the menu titles of grub2 shorter for them to fit in my theme. Namely,

```
  Fedora 38 rescue
```

instead of

```
  Fedora Linux (0-rescue-7ad84fe099814e3388129347d2a46891) 38 (KDE Plasma)
```

and

```
  Fedora 38 (6.2.13-300)
```

instead of

```
  Fedora Linux (6.2.13-300.fc38.x86_64) 38 (KDE Plasma)
```

If I am not mistaken, I should need to edit by hand the file `/etc/grub.d/10_linux`, which is not a trivial task. And, more importantly, this file will be changed by an update of `grub2-tools` package. This is not practical, I want a 'maintenance free' thing.

Is there any way to configure a different grub2 menu title in a persistent way?

I use the `40_custom` file for my menu entries, but the kernel entries are handled automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Add a line

```
export BLS_POPULATE_MENU="true"
```

in `/etc/default/grub`, and change the `title=${value}` line in `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` by

```
title=$(echo "${value}" | sed 's/.../.../')
```

to your liking. Remember to update back the file `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` each time grub2-tools is updated.

Explanation: The menu title is built by the parser in the variable `bls_parser` in `/etc/grub.d/10_linux`, that's why the line in `/etc/default/grub`. This parser obtains the information inside the files in `/boot/loader/entries/`.